# Descendants of an Id

Tags: css, html

I have HTML That looks like this:

```
<section class="container" id="banner">
            <header class="span12" id="header">
                <div class="span3 offset1" id="logo">Logo</div>
                <nav class="span10 offset1" id=bannerNav">
                    <ul>
                        <li>Home</li>
                        <li>Notebook</li>
                        <li>Article Archive</li>
                        <li>Tags</li>
                        <li>About</li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </header>
        </section>
```

with a CSS selector like this:

```
#bannerNav ul li {
    display:inline-block;
    font-size:20px;
}
```

But the list items contained within uls contained within `bannerNav` ids are not being selected, despite the DOM hierarchy resembling what I have created in my constructor. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing a quote before the start of the `id` attribute's value:

```
<nav class="span10 offset1" id=bannerNav">
                               ^
```

Without it, Chrome (and possibly other browsers) assume that the element's ID is `bannerNav"`, which your selector doesn't match.

Answer (score 5):

Maybe the missing quotation mark around the `id` 'bannerNav'?

```
<nav class="span10 offset1" id=bannerNav">
```

Should be ...

```
<nav class="span10 offset1" id="bannerNav">
```